# cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

Sorry, I'm somewhat new to this...I'm getting this error when trying to run a script. Other posts mentioning this error haven't been helpful. Here are some outputs that I've seen other posts mention:

```
uname -a
Linux aaron-850-065se 3.13.0-79-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:27:58 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

file filename
Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable
```

Any ideas how I can get my file run?

Comment: What is the output of `file filename`. What is the content of the script? (Paste it, or at least the first few lines of it, into the post using the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1050160/edit) link. What are the permissions (`ls -l filename`). And last but not least, what is the precise error which you get?

Comment: Does your script begin with `#!/bin/bash` or similar, so the OS knows it's a script?  If not it may be trying to run it as a binary which will fail if it's not actually an executable-format binary.

Comment: To expand on @Hennes' comment, you must have the **read** and **executable** bits set on the file and all the directories in its path (strictly, you don't need **read** on the directories, but you won't be able to browse or auto-complete without it). If it's a script you can run it without the **executable** bit by using the `source` or `.` command, but this isn't a work-round. The `file` command output is important: it will tell you the type of the file (if you can read it), but not whether you can execute it. The `#!` command processor definition is always helpful, but not essential.

Comment: True. I liek the bangpath as well since some errors are caused by editing windows style, causing the bangpath to end in ^m. And a '/bin/bash^M' often does not exist.  But given the title (with info not in the post itself - bad! - it might very well be an arm binary on x86, or a 32 bit binary (not script) on a 64 bit system with no backwared compatability.  I'll guess we'll know when the post gets updated with needed information.

Comment: Are you sure it's a script? `Mach-o executable` is the output for a binary executable file intended for Mac OS X.

Comment: @barmar I do believe that might be an answer. And the question a cautionary tale on knowing what you are running.

Answer (score 6):

`Mach-O 64-bit x86_64 executable` is the binary executable file format used on OS X. If you downloaded this from somewhere, it seems like you downloaded the OS X version rather than the Linux version.